# How to fix "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault' " in python folium geoJSON code?

Tags: python, geojson, folium

How do I get folium to accept geoJSON input which seems to be causing this error?

Trying to do a choropleth map and got the same error so tried to just do a geoJSON overlay on a basic folium map with JSON file I created by taking a subset of a larger geoJSON file. Working in Juypter Notebook. JSON file appears to have correct structure.

msp_map = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=10)

folium.GeoJson(
    msp_zipcode_geo,
    name='geojson'
).add_to(msp_map)

msp_map

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in **call**(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/map.py in _repr_html_(self, **kwargs)
    249             self._parent = None
    250         else:
--> 251             out = self._parent._repr_html_(**kwargs)
    252         return out
    253

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/branca/element.py in _repr_html_(self, **kwargs)
    326 
    327         """
--> 328         html = self.render(**kwargs)
    329         html = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64," + base64.b64encode(html.encode('utf8')).decode('utf8')  # noqa
    330

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/branca/element.py in render(self, **kwargs)
    319         """Renders the HTML representation of the element."""
    320         for name, child in self._children.items():
--> 321             child.render(**kwargs)
    322         return self._template.render(this=self, kwargs=kwargs)
    323

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/map.py in render(self, **kwargs)
    336             ''), name='map_style')
    337 
--> 338         super(LegacyMap, self).render(**kwargs)
    339 
    340

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/branca/element.py in render(self, **kwargs)
    631 
    632         for name, element in self._children.items():
--> 633             element.render(**kwargs)

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/branca/element.py in render(self, **kwargs)
    627         script = self._template.module.**dict**.get('script', None)
    628         if script is not None:
--> 629             figure.script.add_child(Element(script(self, kwargs)),
    630                                     name=self.get_name())
    631

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
    573                             (self.name, len(self.arguments)))
    574 
--> 575         return self._invoke(arguments, autoescape)
    576 
    577     def _invoke(self, arguments, autoescape):

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py in _invoke(self, arguments, autoescape)
    108     def _invoke(self, arguments, autoescape):
    109         if not self._environment.is_async:
--> 110             return original_invoke(self, arguments, autoescape)
    111         return async_invoke(self, arguments, autoescape)
    112     return update_wrapper(_invoke, original_invoke)

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py in _invoke(self, arguments, autoescape)
    577     def _invoke(self, arguments, autoescape):
    578         """This method is being swapped out by the async implementation."""
--> 579         rv = self._func(*arguments)
    580         if autoescape:
    581             rv = Markup(rv)

in macro(l_1_this, l_1_kwargs)

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/runtime.py in call(_Context__self, _Context__obj, *args, **kwargs)
    260                 args = (__self.environment,) + args
    261         try:
--> 262             return __obj(*args, **kwargs)
    263         except StopIteration:
    264             return __self.environment.undefined('value was undefined because '

~/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/features.py in style_data(self)
    563 
    564         for feature in self.data['features']:
--> 565             feature.setdefault('properties', {}).setdefault('style', {}).update(self.style_function(feature))  # noqa
    566             feature.setdefault('properties', {}).setdefault('highlight', {}).update(self.highlight_function(feature))  # noqa
    567         return json.dumps(self.data, sort_keys=True)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

Expecting to get map with overlay of county borders as specified in geoJSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out there was a data type mismatch in the key_on column of data where in the geoJSON file it was string type and in the data set file it was int64. Converting data set file was easier and produced choropleth with the right color range for each polygon in the geoJSON set.

Also figured out that geoJSON file I'd created as a subset of larger geoJSON file was different in that I'd stored some data as dict when it should have been list.